# Table not created in Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a new table called "exercise" in my preexisting database, the two other tables food and users are created normally, but I cannot see the table exercise when using SqliteDatabase Browser. I have upgraded the version of my db and made sure the create_table is done the right way, but nothing, can you please help me find out why that table is not created?

```
public class DatabaseAdapter {

public static final String COLUMN_ID = "ID";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "Name";
public static final String COLUMN_AGE = "Age";
public static final String COLUMN_GENDER = "Gender";
public static final String COLUMN_WEIGHT = "Weight";
public static final String COLUMN_HEIGHT = "Height";
public static final String COLUMN_ACTIVITY = "Activitylevel";
public static final String COLUMN_CALORIES = "numCal";
public static final String FOOD_ID = "food_ID";
public static final String FOOD_NAME = "food_name";
public static final String FOOD_CALS = "food_cals";
public static final String FOOD_FAT = "food_fat";
public static final String FOOD_PRO = "food_protein";
public static final String FOOD_CRAB = "food_crabs";
public static final String EXERCISE_NAME = "exercise_name";
public static final String EXERCISE_CALS = "exercise_cals";
public static final String EXERCISE_ID = "exercise_ID";

public static final String TABLE_USERS = "users";
public static final String TABLE_FOOD = "food";
public static final String TABLE_EXERCISE = "exercise";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 10;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "nutriwellness.db";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_USERS = "create table users( id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "Name text, Age integer, Gender text, Weight text, Height text, Activitylevel text, numCal float );";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_FOOD = "create table food( food_ID integer primary key,"
        + "food_name text,food_cals real, food_fat real, food_protein real, food_crabs real );";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_EXERCISE = "create table exercise( exercise_ID integer primary key,"
        + "exercise_name text,exercise_cals real );";

private SQLiteDatabase database;
private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

private String[] allColumnsofuserstable = { COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_NAME,
        COLUMN_AGE, COLUMN_GENDER, COLUMN_WEIGHT, COLUMN_HEIGHT,
        COLUMN_CALORIES };

private String[] allColumnoffoodtable = { FOOD_ID, FOOD_NAME, FOOD_FAT,
        FOOD_PRO, FOOD_CRAB };
private String[] allColumnofexercisetable = { EXERCISE_ID, EXERCISE_NAME,
        EXERCISE_CALS };

public DatabaseAdapter(Context context) {

    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

public static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 12);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USERS);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_FOOD);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_EXERCISE);
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion
                        + "to version " + newVersion);

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS food");
        db.execSQL("DROP_TABLE IF EXISTS exercise");

        onCreate(db);

    }

}

public DatabaseAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
}

// create a user
public long createUser(String name, String age, String gender,
        String weight, String height, String level, float calnum) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME, name);
    values.put(COLUMN_AGE, age);

    values.put(COLUMN_GENDER, gender);

    values.put(COLUMN_WEIGHT, weight);
    values.put(COLUMN_HEIGHT, height);
    values.put(COLUMN_ACTIVITY, level);
    values.put(COLUMN_CALORIES, calnum);

    return database.insert(TABLE_USERS, COLUMN_ID, values);
}

// delete a user by ID
public boolean deleteUser(long rowId) {
    return database.delete(TABLE_USERS, COLUMN_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

// retrieve a list of all users
public Cursor getAllUsers() {
    return database.query(TABLE_USERS, allColumnsofuserstable, null, null,
            null, null, null);

}

// retrieve a particular user
public Cursor getUser(long rowId) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = database.query(true, TABLE_USERS,
            allColumnsofuserstable, COLUMN_ID + "=" + rowId, null, null,
            null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}

// update a user
public boolean updateUser(long rowId, String Name, int age, String gender,
        String weight, String height, String level, float calnum) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME, Name);
    values.put(COLUMN_AGE, age);

    values.put(COLUMN_GENDER, gender);

    values.put(COLUMN_WEIGHT, weight);
    values.put(COLUMN_HEIGHT, height);
    values.put(COLUMN_ACTIVITY, level);
    values.put(COLUMN_CALORIES, calnum);
    return database.update(TABLE_USERS, values, COLUMN_ID + "=" + rowId,
            null) > 0;
}

// FOOD METHODS !

// Create a new food row
public long createFood(String name, double food_cal, double food_fat,
        double food_proteins, double food_carbs) {
    ContentValues Fvalues = new ContentValues();
    Fvalues.put(FOOD_NAME, name);
    Fvalues.put(FOOD_CALS, food_cal);
    Fvalues.put(FOOD_FAT, food_fat);
    Fvalues.put(FOOD_PRO, food_proteins);
    Fvalues.put(FOOD_CRAB, food_carbs);
    return database.insert(TABLE_FOOD, FOOD_ID, Fvalues);
}

// delete a Food by ID
public boolean deleteFood(long rowId) {
    return database.delete(TABLE_FOOD, FOOD_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

// retrieve a list of all FOOD
public ArrayList<String> getAllfood() {
    Cursor c = database.query(TABLE_FOOD, allColumnoffoodtable, null, null,
            null, null, null);
    ArrayList<String> food = new ArrayList<String>();

    c.moveToFirst();
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
        food.add(c.getString(1));
        c.moveToNext();
    }

    return food;

}

// Retrieve a specific Food

public Cursor getFood(long rowId) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = database.query(true, TABLE_FOOD, allColumnoffoodtable,
            FOOD_ID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}

// Update a food

public boolean updateFood(long rowId, String name, int food_cal,
        int food_fat, int food_proteins, int food_carbs) {
    ContentValues Fvalues = new ContentValues();
    Fvalues.put(FOOD_NAME, name);
    Fvalues.put(FOOD_CALS, food_cal);
    Fvalues.put(FOOD_FAT, food_fat);
    Fvalues.put(FOOD_PRO, food_proteins);
    Fvalues.put(FOOD_CRAB, food_carbs);
    return database
            .update(TABLE_FOOD, Fvalues, FOOD_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

// //////////////////////////////// EXERCISE
// TABLE///////////////////////////////////////////////////

public long createExercise(String name, double exercise_cals) {
    ContentValues Fvalues = new ContentValues();
    Fvalues.put(EXERCISE_NAME, name);
    Fvalues.put(EXERCISE_CALS, exercise_cals);

    return database.insert(TABLE_EXERCISE, EXERCISE_ID, Fvalues);
}

public Cursor getExercise(long rowId) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = database.query(true, TABLE_EXERCISE,
            allColumnofexercisetable, EXERCISE_ID + "=" + rowId, null,
            null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}

public ArrayList<String> getAllexercise() {
    Cursor c = database.query(TABLE_EXERCISE, allColumnofexercisetable,
            null, null, null, null, null);
    ArrayList<String> exercise = new ArrayList<String>();

    c.moveToFirst();
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
        exercise.add(c.getString(1));
        c.moveToNext();
    }

    return exercise;

}

public boolean deleteexercise(long rowId) {
    return database.delete(TABLE_EXERCISE, EXERCISE_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
```

}

Comment: check your logcat, did you get a "Upgrading database from version.." warning or an error? And remove the underscore in `db.execSQL("DROP_TABLE`

Comment: Am i supposed to get that message by just launching my application?

Answer (score 0):

As it stands your code works (all tables were created correctly in my test) so my assumption would be that it is your upgrade code causing the problem.

Perhaps it is because you have hard coded the version number 12 into your openhelper and your previous database was also version 12 so no upgrade is being performed and the database is being left in its current state.

Try changing the version number (use your class constant) and increase the version number whenever you make changes to the database schema. `OnUpgrade` is only called if the specified version is greater than the database version.

i.e

```
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
```

instead of

```
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 12);
    }
```

Also, "DROP_TABLE IF EXISTS exercise" is invalid SQL. remove the underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looking is fine to me but few things to mention

you have declared the database version

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 10;

and have the used 12 in the constructor

```
 public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 12);
        }
```

you might have changed value of DATABASE_VERSION but you are using static value in the constructor.

In upgrade table you have written DROP_TABLE  in last command

```
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS food");

// here you have used  DROP_TABLE 

    db.execSQL("DROP_TABLE IF EXISTS exercise");
```

and what you can do is , simply uninstall the application and install again it will work for you.